# How to concatenate variables in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to concatenate the 'Name' and 'LastName' of the user profile that I fetch from the database. I have the following code in Razor:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
  var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  var fullName = @currentUser.Name + " " + @currentUser.LastName;
  @fullName;
}
else
{
  <span>Guess</span>
}
```

However, when running the site and after log in successfully I got the following error:
**Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement**

I can fix this changing this line of code:

```
@currentUser.Name @currentUser.LastName;
```

This will displayed the Name and Last Name correctly but without the space between them.

Any clue how to solve this?
Regards!

Comment: @currentUser.Name `&nbsp` @currentUser.LastName;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use @ sign in assignment operator try something like below:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
  var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  var fullName = currentUser.Name + " " + currentUser.LastName;
  @fullName;
}
else
{
  <span>Guess</span>
}
```

Or use it like this:

```
@currentUser.Name &nbsp; @currentUser.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @{
   string str1="Hello";
   string str2=" World";
  }
```

You may concatenate as follows

Plain HTML

```
 @str1 @str2
```

Inside code block

```
 @{
   string str3=str1+str2;
  }
```

Inline

```
@(str1+str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove ';'

```
@currentUser.Name @currentUser.LastName
```